# when use asynctask in fragment my app force close

Tags: android

i'm change extend activity to extend fragment and my `AsynkTask` class work well in extend activity but when use in extend fragment and when log in to my app force close i call class `DownloadJson` in on click how should i do please help me

```
public class OmegaFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {



JSONObject jsonobject;
JSONArray jsonarray;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent; 
EditText ocUserName ;
 EditText ocPassword; 

View view;




@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_omega, container, false);

}




   private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create an array
        int isCorrect= 0;
        jsonarray = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(mUrl);


                    EditText ocUserName1 =(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.userNameText);
                    EditText ocPassword1 =(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.passwordText);
                    isCorrect = 1;



        return isCorrect;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer  args) {
        mFragmentCallback.onTaskDone();
        super.onPostExecute(args);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
 public void onClick(View v) {    
    if ( v.getId() == R.id.button1 )
    {
        Button button = (Button) v;

      //  EditText ocUserName =(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.userNameText);
     //   EditText ocPassword =(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.passwordText);
        boolean flag=true;






                            mUrl = global.apiurl +":"+global.apiport+ "/"+global.apiname+"/"+global.controller+"/" + ocUserName.getText().toString() + "/" + ocPassword.getText().toString() + "/0";


                        try {
                             isAccess = (new DownloadJSON().execute()).get();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();  
                        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();  
                        }
                        if ( isAccess == 1 )
                        {
                            Intent intentMain = new Intent(getActivity() ,hozeactivity.class);
```

logcat output :

```
    11-22 23:19:18.822: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1292): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mesbahSoft.quran.OmegaFragment.onClick(OmegaFragment.java:248)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3460)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13955)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: And explain what are you trying to do in doInbackground

Comment: please post your Logcat errors, However i guess you might have some problems with finding views in doInBackground method.

Comment: in doInbackground im download json and save it in db but now i dont need db just need download json

Comment: i can't see your onClick too!

Comment: but my app when use activity work well

Comment: please post your Logcat errors, However i guess you might have some problems with finding views in doInBackground method.

Comment: # Sarthak Mittal  i posted OnClick

Comment: please help me for this problem

Comment: could you please show me line 248 of your code ?

Comment: RadioGroup radioDBGroup = (RadioGroup)view. findViewById(R.id.radioState);

Comment: Are you using onclick property in fragment_omega XML?

Comment: @chy : `view` is `null` becuase in `onCreateView` and `doInBackground` methods you are using different instances of View class with same name `view`. so use `view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_omega, container, false);` in `onCreateView`

Answer (score 0):

As I told you before you have a problem with finding your views. In short delete this lines of code in your doInBackground method and move them in onCreateView. Something like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_omega, container, false);
    EditText ocUserName1 =(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.userNameText);
    EditText ocPassword1 =(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.passwordText);

}
```

in this way you will fix null pointer exception but if you want to send your request to the server you you must call your AsynchTask.
for the rest I suggest you take a look at:

File -> New -> Other -> Android Activity -> LoginActivity

It has a good sample for you to start with.

Comment: im move this to on create but force close

Comment: just please post logcat

Comment: i posted logcat in above

Comment: I guess it will fix if you comment this:
    Button button = (Button) v;
And where is line 248?

Comment: RadioGroup radioDBGroup = (RadioGroup)view. findViewById(R.id.radioState)

Comment: Ok, Thats hard to debug your code without having it but as i see there is no radioGroup used in your code.
delete that line if you haven't use that in your code. But if you have that radioGroup in your xml file and you need that just move it into onCreateView method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65461/discussion-between-milad-and-chy).

Answer (score 0):

Change Your OncreateView() method like below

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_omega, container, false);
    ocUserName1 =(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.userNameText);
    ocPassword1 =(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.passwordText);

}
```

Actually you are using ocUserName1 , ocPassword1  in OnClick method but you did not initialised them. in your on create you assign values to the local variables only that is why prolem occures.

Comment: but yet my app force close

Comment: Are you using onclick property in fragment_omega XML?